# How to store last 'n' day/week/month/year aggregates on a stream of data?

Tags: data-warehouse, aggregation-framework, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

What is the best way to store data in such a way that I can get real time answers of queries like "give me count of last 2 weeks of failed transactions", "give count of accounts created in last 2 years from now". Counting number of rows every time is not an option as number of individual entries in table is huge and may take hours to compute.

I am  only interested in finding aggregates in real time in a rolling window fashion. Also, I do not want to retain data older than 2 years and want that to get removed automatically.

Is there any standard way of solving this problem? Do services like redshift/kinesis be helpful?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most data warehousing solutions, we construct aggregate tables with resolutions down to the business date which makes reporting 2 or more years of data very fast.  Kinesis can certainly help Redshift ingest data at a high throughput which would then allow you to update the day's aggregation counts in real time.  The only difficulty with this approach is that you need to know what aggregations you want to report on ahead of time so you can set them up, but a decent business analyst should be able to provide you with the majority of covering metrics at the start.